# Set case-fold-search in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Emacs doesn't appear to respect `case-fold-search` when set in elisp:

```
(defun test-case (start end)
  "Replace D to Delta in a region."
  (interactive "r")
  (let
      (
       (case-fold-search nil)
       )
    (narrow-to-region start end)

    (goto-char start)
    (while (search-forward-regexp "D" nil t) (replace-match "Delta" nil t))
    )
  )
```

Calling that on `Dublin` return `DELTAublin` while I wanted it to return `Deltaublin`. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to pass 't' instead of 'nil' as the first optional parameter to `(replace-match)`. This should do what you want.

Comment: Wow thanks. `case-fold-search` is for the `search-forward-regexp`.